# Using Javascript to Highlight Child Links on Mouseover & Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a piece of JS that highlights the appropriate child set of links when you mouse-over the parent link.

But now, I'd also like to make the children links highlight when I toggle (click) the respective parent link.

Also, I'd like only one set of children links to be highlights at a time. Meaning, If I click on "Parent 2" Parent 1 will toggle off, and Parent 2 will toggle on.

Hope this makes sense...

Here's the gist of what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Group 1
    $('#one').live('mouseover', function(){
        $('li.uno').addClass('highlight');
    });

    $('#one').live('mouseout', function(){
        $('li.uno').removeClass('highlight');
    }); 

    // Group 2
    $('#two').live('mouseover', function(){
        $('li.dos').addClass('highlight');
    });

    $('#two').live('mouseout', function(){
        $('li.dos').removeClass('highlight');
    }); 

    // Group 3
    $('#three').live('mouseover', function(){
        $('li.tres').addClass('highlight');
    });

    $('#three').live('mouseout', function(){
        $('li.tres').removeClass('highlight');
    }); 

</script>


            <ul><!-- Parent Links -->
                <li id="one">
                    <a href="#">Parent 1</a>                                    
                </li>

                <li id="two">
                    <a href="#">Parent 2</a>                                    
                </li>

                <li id="three">
                    <a href="#">Parent 3</a>                                    
                </li>           
            </ul>


            <ul><!-- Children -->       
                <li class="uno">
                    <a href="">Link<a/>
                </li>

                <li class="tres">
                    <a href="">Link<a/>
                </li>

                <li class="tres">
                    <a href="">Link<a/>
                </li>

                <li class="dos">
                    <a href="">Link<a/>
                </li>

                <li class="uno">
                    <a href="">Link<a/>
                </li>

                <li class="dos">
                    <a href="">Link<a/>
                </li>                               

            </ul>
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting elements, and changing their classes can be slow if you are expecting to be working with a large number elements. Likewise, you probably don't want to have to update the Javascript every time you add a new parent link to your document.

A good way to address this would be to change a single class of a parent element, and let CSS handle the selection and styling of all the child elements.

**I've made a solution that you can [demo at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jbt5/3/).**

Comment: My only question, is how can I make it so only one parent/child set can be selected at a time... Meaning, if I select the link for "Group 2" "Group 1's" will return to normal

Answer (score 0):

Add some class("children") to the `ul` container which contain all the child `li` and try this code.

```
$('#one').live('click', function(){
    $('ul.children li:not(.uno)').slideUp();
    $('ul.children li.uno').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
$('#two').live('click', function(){
    $('ul.children li:not(.dos)').slideUp();
    $('ul.children li.dos').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
$('#three').live('click', function(){
    $('ul.children li:not(.trees)').slideUp();
    $('ul.children li.trees').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ANhJq/2/)**